# WAMPSERVER on windows 8 not starting

Tags: wampserver

I have just installed WAMPSERVER (Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) ) on my WIN 8 machine and when tried to start it, its icon is always RED / orange ( not green ). From services when tried to run the service I see following error message:

[image: wampapache64]

From the even log, I see following multiple errors

```
The wampapache64 service terminated with the following service-specific error: 
Incorrect function.

The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>>> (OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access        permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 

The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>>> (OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access   permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80    

The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>>> AH00015: Unable to open logs    

The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>>> AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down  

The wampapache64 service terminated with the following service-specific error: 
Incorrect function.  

The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>>> (OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access  permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80.
```

Comment: Do you have skype running at the same time?

Comment: Ports below 1024 are usually reserved for privileged users. Have you tried to run it as administrator?

Comment: Yea i am running Skype, i have uncheckded the box which says "Use port80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections" but it did't work.

Comment: I also tried running it from Administrator command prompt. but it throws me following error.   (OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Okay, I figured out: my machine's port 80 was being used by IIS, not by Skype. Here is how I found that:

**Left-click** the WAMPManager icon to reveal the menu. Click **Apache** ► **Service** ► **Test port 80**.
This will launch a command window and display some information about what, if anything is using port 80. You can find more details at  http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,122527.

**Configure Apache to listen on different port**
Since I wanted to keep running IIS on the port 80, I decided to run my WAMP Server on a different port. So here is how I did it.

I had to change `http.conf` file which in my case is in folder `C:/WAMP/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/`. Open it (with Notepad for example) and search for `80`. I had to change the following three lines on different places:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80         # Changed to Listen 0.0.0.0:81
Listen [::0]:80           # Changed to Listen [::0]:81
ServerName localhost:80   # Changed toServerName localhost:81
```

Now I have got the green icon of WAMP Server on Windows 8.

More details on http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,13744.

Comment: This works fine. Port 80 is used by Skype although the cmd does not show it exactly.

Comment: you can also turn off IIS by going to Services -> World Wide Web Publishing Service -> Properties - > Stop. Then set startup type to Manual

Answer (score 7):

If you have Skype running, then you have to do the following within Skype: in the menu bar, click **Tools** ► **Options** ► **Advanced settings** ► **Connection**. Now uncheck the following checkbox:

> Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections

Comment: ok i figured that out. My machine's port 80 was used by IIS, not by SKYPE.

Comment: For me Skype was the problem.Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Champion, thanks mate. That's fairly useless on Skype's part!

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the same problem.

I quit the Skype application and started the wampapache64 service from task manager and that worked for me.