# WAMPserver is not running on windows 8

Tags: windows, wampserver

**WampSever** is not running on windows 8 machine.when tried to start it, it's icon is always red and orange.when i test port 80, I get the following message on the console

```
Your port 80 is not actually used.
press enter to exist...
```

i have follow the instruction of the accepted ans in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978028/wampserver-on-windows-8-not-starting)

but wampserver in not working still icon is ORANGE.

Comment: Try "net stop http" on a command window and then try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First confirm that the services `wampapache64`, `wampmysqld64` are running. If there is a problem with port usage, either change the port and kill `Skype` in `Task Manager` (This was causing the issue for my IIS server) and restart the services.

Another thing, check your firewall rules. The `Apache HTTP Server` rule must be enabled.