# Wampserver is not accessible when other web server is up

Tags: wampserver

I have Wamp server installed and is able to access it, and everything works fine.

but I have other Apache server, when I make this Apache server up and running and I type localhost in browser, I am able to access sites on Apache server.

now when this Apache Server is up I want to access sites from Wampserver as well, so how to do this I am not sure.

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: Well ,the A in WAMP stands for apache so it not possible to have to default configured apaches at the same time. One of the apache installations need to be reconfigured. Easiest is to change the port for one of them in httpd.conf. It will then be accessed via http://localhost:<port>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your default port is used by some other applications.
Have a look at this
[WAMPSERVER on windows 8 not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978028/wampserver-on-windows-8-not-starting)